# crontab doesnt work for run java class

Tags: java, linux, cron

**testjob.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/jdk1.6.0_07
echo "Java Home is $JAVA_HOME"
export CLASSPATH=.:..:$CLASSPATH:
echo "Path is is $PATH"
echo "CLASSPATH is is $CLASSPATH"
$JAVA_HOME/bin/java  TestJob
echo "$JAVA_HOME/bin/java  TestJob"
```

**crontab -e**

```
* * * * * /usr/testjob.sh  >> /usr/result.txt 2>&1
```

if i run shell script manually it runs fine but when it will run through crontab job, error will occur as class not found..

please suggest..

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at this. Should answer your question

[Where can I set environment variables that crontab will use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2229825/where-can-i-set-environment-variables-that-crontab-will-use)

Again read this http://linuxshellaccount.blogspot.com/2007/10/crontab-and-your-environment.html\

The easiest way you can make sure that you have same environment in cron as you have when running any script as the regular user is to "source" the environment into the script by adding a line like:

. /etc/profile
. /home/user/.profile

to the top of your script (below the #! line). The literal dot, space, filename patterns tells your shell to read in all variables in that named file, so you could run your cron job with the same environment as when you test it manually, which might avoid issues caused by points 1 and 2 above.

Answer (score 1):

Your classpath is set as "." and "..", which means the current directory and it's parent directory.  So when you run it locally, you'll have to be in a particular directory for it to work.

Try setting the classpath to an absolute directory in your script.

To check which directory is the current directory you may also want to put

```
echo "Current directory: `pwd`"
```

into your `testjob.sh` script to illustrate the differences when invoking "manually" and through crontab.