# script behaves differently via cron

Tags: bash, cron

Edit: Updated to reflect some answers

I have this script, test.sh on my home computer:

Note: $USER = john

```
#!/bin/bash 
/usr/bin/scp -q john@mysite.com:/home/$USER/tmp/$USER /home/$USER/tmp/ > /dev/null 2>&1
error_code="$?"

if [ "$error_code" != "0" ]; then    #if file NOT present on mysite then:
        echo "File does not exist."
        exit
fi
echo "File exists."
```

Now, lets say I create the file on the server mysite.com like so:

```
echo > tmp/$USER
```

Now, when I run the above script on my desktop manually, like so:

```
./test.sh
```

I get the result "File exists."

But if I run it via crontab, I get the result "File does not exist"
My crontab looks like this:

```
* * * * * /home/user/test.sh >> /home/user/test.log 2>&1
```

I've spent all day trying to check the logic and everything... I can't seem to figure out why this is so. Thanks for all your help in advance :)

**Edit**: scp looks in mysite.com:/home/$USER/tmp/ dir
The $USER on my desktop and the server are same. So I don't think it's an issue of relativeness. 
If I were to

```
ssh $USER@mysite.com
```

and then do

```
ls tmp/
```

I'll see the file there.

Also, the crontab entry is in my crontab, not another users' or root's crontab.

@Jonathan: I've set up key based authentication. No password required!

@netcoder: In my log file, I see repeated lines of "File does not exist."

@sarnold: in my scp line, I've put john@mysite.com, just to make sure that cron uses john's account on mysite.com when crond runs the script. Still, same result.

Comment: Have you tried the absolute path to `scp` (i.e.: `/usr/bin/scp`) or `/tmp`?. What user do you run the cron as? What's the working directory of the crons? What's in test.log?

Comment: And an adjunct to @netcoder's question - what is in `/dev/null`?  Since it won't tell you, I suggest you capture the standard output and standard error in a file so you can see whether the information you need is in there.  For example, how does `scp` know which password to use?

Answer (score 1):

I expect the problem is right here: `mysite.com:tmp/$USER` -- `tmp/` is a relative path, relative to the current working directory. When your code is executed via `crond(8)`, your `cwd` might be different than when you execute it by hand.

As [@netcoder points out in his comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8251206/script-behaves-differently-via-cron#comment-10152877), absolute paths are the best way to work with scripts / programs executed out of `crontab(5)` files.

Answer (score 1):

It may be a problem with your `$USER` environment variable not being set when run under cron.

You could try adding something like this to your script:

```
echo "User: $USER" > /tmp/crontest.log
```

After getting cron to run the script have a look at what is in /tmp/crontest.log

If nothing is being set you might want to try something like this: [Where can I set environment variables that crontab will use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2229825/where-can-i-set-environment-variables-that-crontab-will-use)