# How do I add pre-hook and post-hook scripts that run before all of my cron jobs?

Tags: unix, cron, hook

Suppose I have the following cron entry:

```
* * * * * /bin/date
```

Now suppose that I want scripts that run both before and after the cron job runs.

I could modify the cron entry to look like this:

```
* * * * * /bin/prehook ; /bin/date ; /bin/posthook
```

Or if I wanted the exit code of the prehook to determine whether or not the date command runs, I could do this:

```
* * * * * /bin/prehook && /bin/date ; /bin/posthook
```

However, I'm looking for a solution that I might be able to apply globally to all cron jobs without editing every single crontab; I see this as analogous to pre-commit and post-commit hooks that you see in many version control systems.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there exists an easy solution using a standard cron implementation like Vixie cron unmodified.

Wrapping all the jobs in a single crontab should be achievable quite easily by setting SHELL in the crontab to a custom wrapper script, but there doesn't seem to be a way to globally configure the default shell used.

If moving away to another cron implementation is an option, then eg. [bcron](http://untroubled.org/bcron/) seems to use a global wrapper script for similar purposes. But I have no idea how alive and usable this project is.

Answer (score 0):

The system I use is that a `crontab` entry always consists of a single script name, such as:

```
3  1  *  *  *  /home/me/bin/Cron/daily
```

The script in `/home/me/bin/Cron/daily` is actually a link to a single script, `runcron`, which looks at what it is called (e.g. `daily`).  It sets my environment (since `cron` does not set more than the very barest of minimal environments), and then runs `/home/me/bin/daily`.  If (when) I need to debug cron, or add pre-hooks or post-hooks, I can do it globally (by modifying `/home/me/bin/Cron/runcron`) or locally (by making `/home/me/bin/Cron/daily` temporarily into a modified copy of the normal `runcron` script).  This flexibility is very useful on those occasions when I need it, and doesn't involve any change in the actual `crontab` entry.

My scripts do relay arguments if they're provided.  I've never found sufficient reason to use that functionality in the long term, though.  I have entries for `daily`, `weekday`, `weekly` and `monthly`.   (See also [Where can I set environment variables that crontab will use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2229825/where-can-i-set-environment-variables-that-crontab-will-use))

Comment: Your solution modifies cron; ideally I wouldn't have to change every single cron entry. But the wrapper solution may be the way I need to go.