# Bash script into crontab behaving differently

Tags: bash, encoding, cron, environment

I'm having trouble in finding the reason why my BASH script behaves differently if run alone or inside `cron`. I have this snippet:

```
    #!/bin/bash
    RESPONSE=$(curl -fs -XPOST -H "Content-type: application/json" -d '{"id" : 4}' https://myserver.com)
    echo $RESPONSE

    if [ -z "$RESPONSE" ]; then
        echo "empty response"
        return 0
    fi

    COMMAND=$(echo $RESPONSE | python -c "import sys, json; print json.load(sys.stdin)['command']")
    if [ -z "$COMMAND" ]; then
        echo "empty command"
    elif [ "$COMMAND" = "SYS_INFO" ];
    then
        #business logic
    fi
```

that prints two different responses in the two environments:

```
$RESPONSE Running from console:
{"id":"1f78d8d0-e754-4a23-a2f0-448fbeb42995", "key":"\n4RHDFAnTull1Z+aHGbO1zXcAGghuaEUz0w8sT7dlpc80jG6ZaWnbDox4G0f8sKY\ng0WZ80zWf8ftNgX3nes9MWYEq00nM5jJWCSavmGSKCKjoGD2XqBod8W0Z5w/KAHTSitGVMFgMjda91+xozw8uMlzR/t3Y8FP2k/NHj\n"}

$RESPONSE Running from :
{"id":"1f78d8d0-e754-4a23-a2f0-448fbeb42995", "key":"
4RHDFAnTull1Z+aHGbO1zXcAGghuaEUz0w8sT7dlpc80jG6ZaWnbDox4G0f8sKYj
g0WZ80zWf8ftNgX3nes9MWYEq00nM5jJWCSavmGSKCKjoGD2XqBod8W0Z5w/KAHTSitGVMFgMjda91+xozw8uMlzR/t3Y8FP2k/NHj
"}
```

Please notice the `\n` that the server returns into `key` field that are present when running from console and NOT present (actually, they are encoded as newline) when running from crontab

What I've tried:

1. adding source ~/.bashrc as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9873034/bash-script-returns-different-value-when-run-from-cron-job-than-from-command-lin)
2. changing value of PATH evaluating the differences of the two environments as suggested [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/23009/why-crontab-scripts-are-not-working)

However, nothing seems to work.

Comment: Please include the code you use to run it. It sounds like in the latter case, you're running it with sh

Comment: Why are you capturing the result into a variable at all? [You should quote the variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067266/when-to-wrap-quotes-around-a-shell-variable) and probably use `printf` instead of `echo` for proper portability; but really, just do `curl -fs -XPOST -H "Content-type: application/json" -d '{"id" : 4,}' https://myserver.com` without the variable capture.

Comment: I've updated the question.
When I'm running the code via console i'm using bash, when I'm running the script with cron I think i'm using bash as well... considering the hashbang value...

I'm capturing the result since I'm parsing it later on (I'm using inline-python instead of other solution eg. jq)

Comment: Try `echo “$RESPONSE”` with double quotes.