# Declaring environment variables listed in a file used in perl shell

Tags: perl, shell, unix, environment-variables

I have a file "temp.txt" containing

```
var1=hello
var2=ello
var3=mello
....and a long list
```

in unix shell we can simply use `. temp.txt` is use all the variables in the file..

do we have a similar function in perl or any work around..

I tried a workaround

```
$ cat checkDOTfuctionOFunix.ksh
#!/bin/ksh
. /export/home/temp.txt
#export

/export/home/checkDOTfuncPRINTSinPERL.pl

$ cat /export/home/checkDOTfuncPRINTSinPERL.pl
#!/usr/local/bin/perl

print "var1=$ENV{var1} \n\n var2=$ENV{var2} \n\n";
```

but this wont work unless I export each value which can be done with simple `sed -e 's/^/export/` but I prefer not to do this. please help :)

Answer (score 1):

```
set -a
. temp.txt
set +a
./checkDOTfuncPRINTSinPERL.pl
```

with set -a as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14904142/export-variables-defined-in-another-file), all variable assignments promote the variable to an environment variable.
[Here](http://man.cx/set) some doc to shell set options.

Comment: Cheers!! this works.. but is there a command like this in perl... I would like to avoid calling the perl script from ksh shell script and directly use `temp.txt` file in `checkDOTfuncPRINTSinPERL.pl`

Answer (score 0):

This is now possible in Perl with the [`Env::Modify` module](http://metacpan.org/pod/Env::Modify).

```
use Env::Modify 'source';
source("temp.txt");     # like saying  . temp.txt  in the shell
.. env settings in  temp.txt  are now available to Perl ...
```