# How to run cron as non root user?

Tags: linux, cron

I have been trying to run a command on scheduled basis via a cron job.
I am logged in as a non-root user. The command requires the exact PATH (bash_profile) of user.
I tried to exporting the PATH using `/home/<user>/.bash_profile` file but it is not exporting the entire path.
Any help?

Comment: Did you see [other answers](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/27289/how-can-i-run-a-cron-command-with-existing-environmental-variables) ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Where can I set environment variables that crontab will use?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2229825/where-can-i-set-environment-variables-that-crontab-will-use)