# Crontab cannot find AWS Credentials - linuxbox EC2

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, cron

I've created a linux box that has a very simple make bucket command : was `s3 mb s3://bucket` running this from the prompt works fine.

I've run AWS configure as both the user I'm logged in as and sudo.  The details are definitely correct as the above wouldn't create the bucket.

The error message I'm getting from cron is `:make_bucket failed: s3://cronbucket/ Unable to locate credentials`

I've tried various things thus far with the crontab in trying to tell it where the credentials are, some of this is an amalgamation of other solutions which may be a cause of the issue.

My crontab look like :

```
AWS_CONFIG_FILE="/home/ec2-user/.aws/config"
SHELL=/bin/bash
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/binx
0 0 * * * /usr/bin/env bash /opt/foo.sh &>> /tmp/foo.log

* * * * * /usr/bin/uptime > /tmp/uptime

* * * * * /bin/scripts/script.sh >> /bin/scripts/cronlogs/cronscript.log 2>&1
```

initially I just had the two jobs that were making the bucket and then creating the uptime (as a sanity check), the rest of the crontab are solutions from other posts that do not seem to be working.

Any advice is much appreciated, thank you.

Comment: You should use IAM roles.

Comment: I couldn't for this particular scenario

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that cron doesn't get your env. There are several ways of approaching this. Either running a bash script that includes your profile. Or a nice simple solution would be to include it with crontab. (change profile to whatever you are using)

```
0 5 * * * . $HOME/.profile; /path/to/command/to/run
```

check out this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2229825/where-can-i-set-environment-variables-that-crontab-will-use)

Comment: Thanks, I'm now trying that solution, the Home dir is set, the .profile was blank so I copied across .aws/config to .profile and am now waiting for the job to run

Comment: same error I'm afraid - this is the command: * * * * * . $HOME/.profile; /bin/script/script.sh >> /bin/script/cronlogs/cronscript.log 2>&1

Comment: although I notice that there mail message I receive is trying to use root@ip instead of my user, perhaps that's the issue

Comment: you should try to include $HOME/.bash_profile or $HOME/.bashrc depends on your system. or even /etc/profile.

Comment: so adding the lines in the was config (region, access key, secret, output) to the bash profile by exporting them I guess(?) should work?

Comment: By including bash_profile/bashrc the cli tools like AWS cli should be able to locate the .aws/config file location

Answer (score 2):

If you have attached IAM role for ECS Fargate task role then this solution will work
Add the following line in the `entrypoint.sh`

```
declare -p | grep -Ev 'BASHOPTS|BASH_VERSINFO|EUID|PPID|SHELLOPTS|UID' > /container.env
```

Add below line in crontab or cron file

```
SHELL=/bin/bash
BASH_ENV=/container.env
```

It worked for me.

Comment: Posted a long time ago, but this is what helped me today, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In my case it was much trickier, because I was running a CRON job in Fargate instance, and I could access S3 from shell, but it did not work from CRON.

1. In Dockerfile configure the CRON job

   ```
    RUN echo -e \                                                                
    "SHELL=/bin/bash\n\                                                          
    BASH_ENV=/app/cron/container.env\n\n\                                        
    30 0 * * * /app/cron/log_backup.sh >> /app/cron/cron.log 2>&1" | crontab -
   ```
2. In entrypoint script configure AWS credentials

   ```
   creds=`curl 169.254.170.2$AWS_CONTAINER_CREDENTIALS_RELATIVE_URI`
   AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=`echo $creds | jq .'AccessKeyId' | tr -d '"'`
   AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=`echo $creds | jq '.SecretAccessKey' | tr -d '"'`
   AWS_SESSION_TOKEN=`echo $creds | jq '.Token' | tr -d '"'`
   ```
3. After that in same entrypoint script create container.env file as **@Tailor Devendra** suggested in previous solution:

   ```
   declare -p | grep -Ev 'BASHOPTS|BASH_VERSINFO|EUID|PPID|SHELLOPTS|UID' > /app/cron/container.env
   ```

I can't say that I am happy with this solution, but it works.