# Cron: Setting PATH from shell script not working

Tags: linux, shell, path, cron

I wrote a simple shell script in centOS and executing this from a cron job.
My script looks like below:

```
#!/bin/bash

export PATH=$PATH:$(pwd) 
echo $PATH
echo $PATH| mail -s "PATH" me@gmail.com
```

And if I execute this script directly from terminal, it outputs below:

```
/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/vagrant
```

where /vagrant is the one I expected.

But if this is executed from cron job, it outputs (in my mail) like:

```
/usr/bin:/bin:/root
```

How I can set /vagrant properly when executed from a cron job?

UPDATE: I can set the /vagrant as PATH but it will work for me only. If I deploy my script to some other user, they have to make this directory. So I want to make the script like it will export the location from where it is running.

In my case , my script is running from /vagrant but the current directory is being exported as /root. This is the problem.

UPDATE: Sadly speaking, path was exported correctly but files from the /vagrant directory was reported to be not found.

Comment: Well, by specifying `/vagrant`. `$(pwd)` resolves the the current working directory, which depends on the situation.

Comment: `cron` runs in a different environment, so you cannot assume the same values as when you run with your user. If you want to add `/vagrant`, just hardcode it. If you want to use variables, check [Where can I set environment variables that crontab will use?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37183809/1983854)

Comment: Also, what do yo want to use: the current working directory (pwd) or the directory where the script is?

Comment: The directory where the script is.

Comment: For this part you may want to check [Can a Bash script tell what directory it's stored in?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/59895/1983854).

Answer (score 1):

A `cron` job runs in the owner's home directory, so that's what `pwd` results in when it runs. Just put the directory you want instead.

```
PATH=$PATH:/vagrant
```

Incidentally, you can't (reliably) use the Bash syntax `export variable=value` because Cron runs plain `sh`. Anyway, there should be no need to `export` the `PATH` variable, because it is already exported, inherently (it couldn't work if it wasn't).

Comment: cron can run whatever you ask it to, doesn't it? You can say `* * * * * /bin/bash /home/me/script.sh`.

Comment: @fedorqui You are correct of course; though one possible error is if the OP isn't running the script through the shebang, or is specifying `sh` explicitly in spite of the shebang. Anyway, I guess this is moot now.