# Crontab execution location from the rest of scripts

Tags: php, scripting, debian, cron

I have like 40+ cronjob files which are all over the place in a legacy code. 
Can I somehow set the base directory of the cronjob so I only have to type the rest of the path? 
Like:

```
#old non refactored PhP scripts still running on this server
cd /data1/www/xxxx/htdocs/deploy
*    *  * * *   root soap/xxxxxeue-runner.php
```

Any suggestions?
I am running 
Debian 8+ with php 5.6 if it is of any help

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25723723/5857047

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this is not possible with crontab.

You may be interested in [systemd timers](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Systemd/Timers), or — assuming that all of your scripts run at `* * * * *` — you could make a single cron script that calls the rest of them.