# Cannot run perforce from crontab

Tags: perl, cron, perforce, cron-task

I am trying to execute perl script that works with perforce, from crontab. This is my perl code:

```
print `/usr/local/bin/p4 filelog /projects/config.json`;
```

I am getting error:

```
Perforce client error:
    Connect to server failed; check $P4PORT.
    TCP connect to perforce:1666 failed.
    Name or service not known
```

The same command is working smoothly from cli. Any ideas what can i do with it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because you don't have the `P4CONFIG` (or alternative) environment vars are set in your cron environment. You simply need to replicate the environment vars you have in your interactive shell (perhaps using `set | grep ^P4` to determine what they are).

Find more details about setting env vars [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2229825/589924).

Comment: I added P4PORT to the command, but still getting the same error. Here is my cron line: `46  4  *  *  *    P4PORT=ss-5:1666 PERL5LIB=/lib /tmp/test >> /tmp/cronoutput 2>&1`

Comment: I thought it went without saying, but you simple need to replicate the P4 env vars you have in your interactive environment (`set | grep ^P4`). There shouldn't be any guessing!

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution is to set the env vars in perl code:

```
    $ENV{'P4PORT'} = '...';
    $ENV{'P4CLIENT'} = '...';
    $ENV{'P4USER'} = '...';
    $ENV{'P4PASSWD'} = '...';
```

Comment: Setting up these environment variables is what the existing answer instructs you to do. However. it suggests setting them in the crontab file, which is a far better solution than hardcoding config data in your script. That's a bad solution.

Comment: @ikegami, existing solution does not explain how exactly to set them in crontab file. If you could add this information, it would help a lot. Thanks.

Comment: If you are unable to determine how to set variables in a crontab after reading the documentation (`man 5 crontab`), feel free to ask a question about it. You can also ask the shell to set them (`VAR=val command`).

Comment: @ikegami, I believe, the goal of stackoverflow is to provide focused and complete answers to the people's questions, even if the answers can be found in the documentation.

Comment: Yes indeed. That's why I said you should feel free to ask that question. Actually, it's already been [asked](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2229825/589924).

Comment: Cool. Could you please add this link to your answer to make it the best?

Comment: @ikegami, I added the link to your post and marked it as most helpful.