# Sqlplus command not found when running from crontab

Tags: linux, oracle, bash, cron

This is the case, I made 3 files to execute backup database command in *rman*

### test.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
sqlplus /nolog @/u01/conectar.sql
```

### conectar.sql:

```
connect sys/manager as sysdba
ho rman target mydatabase/mypassword @/u01/backup.sh
```

### backup.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
RUN {backup database;}
```

and then I did all the `chmod u+x` for the files to make them executable, then `export EDITOR=nano` to change the cron editor.

when I go to `crontab -e i put`

```
00 15 * * * /u01/test.sh
```

If I clic this test.sh manually, the operation runs normally, but then in the crontab I get the "you got a mail" thing with this message

> From root@localhost.localdomain  Thu Dec 22 16:20:01 2016
>   Return-Path: 
>   X-Original-To: oracle
>   Delivered-To: oracle@localhost.localdomain
>   Received: by localhost.localdomain (Postfix, from userid 500)
>   id 956CD41D4B; Thu, 22 Dec 2016 16:20:01 -0400 (AST)
>   From: root@localhost.localdomain (Cron Daemon)
>   To: oracle@localhost.localdomain
>   Subject: Cron  /u01/test.sh
>   Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
>   Auto-Submitted: auto-generated
>   X-Cron-Env: 
>   X-Cron-Env: 
>   X-Cron-Env: 
>   X-Cron-Env: 
>   X-Cron-Env: 
>   Message-Id: <20161222202001.956CD41D4B@localhost.localdomain>
>   Date: Thu, 22 Dec 2016 16:20:01 -0400 (AST)
>   /u01/test.sh: line 3: sqlplus: command not found"

Please can you remake the script or the crontab for me? If you can answer with the exactly modifications I would appreciate it, I'm not an expert in this environment so a general *knowledge needed* answer will leave me the same, thanks.

Comment: Try to set set PATH for `ORACLE_HOME/bin` or just run SQL*PLUS as `ORACLE_HOME/bin/sqlplus `.

Comment: thanks, now where should i add `ORACLE_HOME/bin` or what to do specifically?

Comment: [Possible duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2229825/266304), or at least related. You need to set up the Oracle environment in your bash script - possibly by sourcing your existing `~/.bash_profile`; or you can source that as part of the crontab entry (shown in an answer on that question).

Comment: ok, what file do i need to modify in order to do that?

Comment: @Robenya : In your bash script.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it in many ways:

1. Just before the cron line:

   `PATH=$PATH:/full/path/to/oracle/bin`
2. Or on the cron line itself:

   `00 15 * * * PATH=$PATH:/full/path/to/oracle/bin /u01/test.sh`
3. Let your script `test.sh` source another shared script that sets up your Oracle environment:

   `source /path/to/oracle_env.sh`

I prefer the third method because it is very flexible and it helps us keep the crontab uncluttered.  .bash_profile should be meant for interactive shell only - it is not good to share it with scheduled scripts, especially in production.

Comment: Hi @codeforester, tried to locate oracle_env.sh and couldn't find it, can You help me in that please?