# Scheduled cron job not working

Tags: linux

I have a script abc.sh and I have scheduled it in crontab.now abc.sh is calling another script using sudo. When I am executing abc.sh manually it is working fine..but from scheduler abc.sh is running every 5 minutes but It is unable to call another script using sudo. This is strange for me..can any one help me on this please

Comment: Does sudo has allowed passwordless execution of abc.sh child script?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, @AMITGHOSH.  Please review: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. In particular, you will want to supply some details on your scripts and cron configuration.

Comment: Yes..my child script does not require any password...manually I tested..and working as expected

Comment: sudo  /opt/clearcache.sh...this is what abc.sh is calling

Answer (score 1):

You can take a look at `/var/mail/<username>` file to see if cron job is sending some error or warning message. Or maybe you have not set executable permissions for the `/opt/clearcache.sh` file?

Comment: I didn't find recent cron related log in above mentioned directory...even no problem with executable permissions.i have sudo access to clearcache.sh file

Answer (score 0):

This happens often when people use sudo.
The environment YOU use is not set for the privileged user. As such, your $PATH and other environment variables may not be set as you expect.
You can set this up, or change the sudo behavior... however most people simply work-around this by using full paths to files in cron.

Have a look at this post as well: [Where can I set environment variables that crontab will use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2229825/where-can-i-set-environment-variables-that-crontab-will-use)