# f.write(r.text) stops working in cron-job

Tags: python, cron, raspberry-pi3

I have a very basic website-scraper running on my rapsberry pi.

```
r = get(url)
with open('filename.html', 'w') as f:
        f.write(r.text)
```

Running it in the terminal works as expected. But running it via a cron job gives the following error (found it via mailx)

```
f.write(r.text)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u2019' in position 67005: ordinal not in range(128)
```

What causes the script to work when used via the terminal:

```
>python thescript.py
```

But it does not work using

```
30 9 * * * python /home/pi/thescript.py
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with `cron`

Comment: Any ideas what causes this behavior?

Comment: It's likely that you don't have setup the Environment for `cron`. Read [where-can-i-set-environment-variables-that-crontab-will-use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2229825/where-can-i-set-environment-variables-that-crontab-will-use)