# How to use env .bashrc variables on crontab?

Tags: cron, environment-variables

I need to send a personal `env` variable `$FTP111_PASSWD` defined at my personal `.bashrc`  to `crontab` execution. **How to set an environment variable on crontab?**

My original shell script, named `cron4_etc.sh`, created for `crontab` execution was:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

cd /myFolder/
ftp -n -i <<EOF
open 101.111.111.111
user myUser "$FTP111_PASSWD"
mget check_*.log
bye
EOF
```

If I execute the script via terminal `./cron4_etc.sh` it is executing fine, but if I have start it using the following `crontab` line

```
  */20 *     *   *   *     /home/myUser/cron4_etc.sh > /tmp/cron4.log 2>&1
```

crontab says

> *Password: Login incorrect.\nLogin failed.*

I tried to improve my script using [this suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58725211/287948), but the error persists:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# set environment
source /home/myUser/.bashrc

cd /tmp/pg_io/PGW
ftp -n -i <<EOF
open 101.111.111.111
user myUser "$FTP111_PASSWD"
mget check_*.log
bye
EOF
```

PS: I am using Ubuntu 18 LTS, but the question is for generic crontab.

Comment: Did you check out the answers to [this post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/67940/cron-ignores-variables-defined-in-bashrc-and-bash-profile) and especially [this one](https://askubuntu.com/a/1080812/133393), which explains the pitfalls of using Ubuntu’s default .bashrc in non-interactive shells?

Comment: Thanks @amain, make sense. The correct question seems this two steps: 1. Where the best place to my `$FTP_etc_PASSWD` variables, `.bash_profile`?  2. how to "run this place" at my Crontab script? ... Or the best is put in `/etc/environment `?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My favorite solution comes from [Augusto Destrero](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2393703/augusto-destrero), who provided the following [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34492957/8330162) to a very similar question:

> Setting vars in `/etc/environment` also worked for me in Ubuntu. As of 12.04, variables in /etc/environment are loaded for cron.

Some people suggest to do a simple `env >> /etc/environment` to append all your environment variables, but I would be careful with that and rather review `/etc/environment` manually.

Comment: Hi B--rian, thanks, good clues and explanations!   Can you show a script? (I will copy/paste and test it, I need a full "recipe for dummies").. Need to start with `#!/bin/bash` or other magic that you must explain.

Comment: .... Seem that it is **not** the best answer at cited answer page, the best is the simplest and runs with UBUNTU 20 LTS also, is a simple "add `-l` option", see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51591762/287948).

Comment: Well, my solution does not really require a script, and I just said that it is my preferred solution *for Ubuntu* since it bundles all environment variables on a single location. `bash -l`works as well, and so does the accepted answer of the question I quoted.

Comment: Oops, @amain remember that is not a good practice to run `.bashrc` on crontab... So, your answer shows the best choice and a good practice. I tested and crontab is running `/etc/environment`!