# I have a crontab entry that calls a bash script. Why does $USER return blank?

Tags: linux, bash, cron

In the monitor shell script, `$USER` returns blank when run from a user's crontab?  However, `$USER` returns "experiment" when the script is run from the command line.

```
# CRON: execute monitor script every minute on user:experiment
*/1 * * * * /home/experiment/monitor
```

Comment: I think you'll find that most of the environment variables are not set. Run a crontab job where you log it `env > /tmp/env.log` If you want some variables set you can do that at the top of the crontab file (in most implementations).

Comment: @TedLyngmo I am new to this... could you give a link

Comment: The crontab man page: https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/crontab.5.html, see "environment setting" in the first section.

Comment: Where you can set environmental variables in your `crontab` file depends on the version of cron.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2229825/where-can-i-set-environment-variables-that-crontab-will-use. Look at the `crontab(5)` manpage for your OS version.

Comment: The way to see the man page from the shell is `man crontab`.  In some cases you have to specify the "section" of the manual as `man 5 crontab`.  That's what the 5 in `crontab(5)` is above.

Comment: As the crontab(5) man page indicates, use LOGNAME instead.

Comment: I could get the user across using USER=experiment.

Comment: However I need the full scope to be in "experiment".  I tried  ` */1 * * * * . $HOME/.profile; /home/experiment/username `  as suggest else where... but didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested in the comments, `cron` uses a rather minimal environment, with most of the environment variables undefined, and a very short `$PATH`. In many versions of `crontab`, you can define the variables you need at the top of the `crontab` file, like so:

```
USER=foo
BAR=baz
PATH=/bletch:/bazoo:"$PATH"
```