# Simple cronjob to print time and variable from Linux .bashrc "raise KeyError(key) from None"

Tags: python, linux, cron, environment-variables

I have a cronjob to run a Python program, `test.py`, and save its output to `test.log`.

Output of `sudo crontab -l`:

```
* * * * * python3 /path/to/test.py/ >> /path/to/test.log 2>&1
```

Contents of `test.py`:

```py
import os
import datetime
NOW = datetime.datetime.now()
print(NOW)
print(os.environ['some_var_in_bashrc']) # export some_var_in_bashrc="99999"
```

Contents of `~/.bashrc`:

```sh
...

export some_var_in_bashrc="99999"
```

When running from terminal, output is as expected...

```
$ python3 test.py
2021-02-01 15:49:02.165106
99999
```

When the cronjob runs I get this in `test.log`:

```
2021-02-01 15:49:01.341941
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/path/to/test.py/", line 8, in <module>
    print(os.environ['some_var_in_bashrc'])
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/os.py", line 669, in __getitem__
    raise KeyError(key) from None
KeyError: 'some_var_in_bashrc'
```

Why does this happen?

I am on Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Where can I set environment variables that crontab will use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2229825/where-can-i-set-environment-variables-that-crontab-will-use)

Comment: yes, thank you i was searching for a few days but couldnt find.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that cron doesn't have access to shell's Env var by default. So try adding your cronjob like this:

```
* * * * * some_var_in_bashrc="99999" python3 /path/to/test.py/ >> /path/to/test.log 2>&1
```

Comment: how can i set another variable? will this work?
* * * * * some_var_in_bashrc="99999";another_variable="111111" python3 /path/to/test.py/ >> /path/to/test.log 2>&1