# java: command not found and JAVA_HOME is empty in scripts from crontab

Tags: java, cron, java-home

I installed java 18 using this tutorial: https://computingforgeeks.com/install-oracle-java-18-on-ubuntu-debian/ Scripts (.sh) running at reboot from crontab doesn't have any JAVA_HOME and default PATH variables. When I run these scripts manually it works. After rebooting it's the same.
I tried putting
JAVA_HOME = /opt/jdk-18
PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin
to my crontab -e as of this thread : [Where can I set environment variables that crontab will use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2229825/where-can-i-set-environment-variables-that-crontab-will-use)
but now scripts are not even running (in /var/log/syslog there is CMD (sh /script-to-run.sh), manually it works.

Comment: `JAVA_HOME = /opt/jdk-18` should not have spaces around `=`. Yes that matters. Also, what happens if you set JAVA_HOME in the script (instead of in crontab).

Comment: I fixed spaces, after adding JAVA_HOME to /etc/environment I see it in the script,  but still got:  sh: java: command not found

Comment: `echo $PATH` and make sure `/opt/jdk-18/bin` is there. If it isn't, then you know why. If it is, then do a `which java` where `java` actually works for you.

Comment: I created symlink with ln -s /opt/jdk-18/bin/java /usr/bin/java and it worked, thanks for help. :)

Comment: I use (and recommend) [sdkman](https://sdkman.io/).