# Shell script works standalone, but doesn't work with crontab, despite of normal logging

Tags: cron

I wrote a simple script file,

`test.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "hi"
```

And in `crontab -e` file, I wrote as follows:

```
# m h  dom mon dow   command
40 14 * * * /var/lib/postgres/backup/test.sh >> /var/lib/postgres/backup/test.log
```

This is part of system log, `/var/log/syslog`.

```
Jan 23 14:40:01 ubuntu cron[538576]: (postgres) RELOAD (crontabs/postgres)
Jan 23 14:40:01 ubuntu CRON[548129]: (postgres) CMD (/var/lib/postgres/backup/test.sh >> /var/lib/postgres/backup/test.log 2>&1)
```

no more logs

However, I cannot find any test.log file.
It works standalone well.
Do you have any idea?

Environment: Raspberry Pi 3 Model B Plus Rev 1.3
Linux ubuntu 5.4.0-1098-raspi #110-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT Mon Nov 13 13:43:55 UTC 2023 aarch64 aarch64 aarch64 GNU/Linux

Something to note:
My cron log setting

```
postgres@ubuntu:~/backup$ sudo cat /etc/rsyslog.d/50-default.conf | grep cron
#cron.*                         /var/log/cron.log
#       cron,daemon.none;\
```

-> cron logs are being written on syslog file.

I tried to backup my postgreSQL database, so I'm using postgres account.
Yesterday, there were some error logs about postfix. After installing and configuring postfix, the error logs related with postfix were gone.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Crontab entries do not automatically have the same environment as your login shell.  There are a large number of questions detailing this on SO.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Where can I set environment variables that crontab will use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2229825/where-can-i-set-environment-variables-that-crontab-will-use)